# Can't add my Widget to a layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Why can't I add my widget to the layout? It is like the [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html) for adding Widgets... 
My aim is to draw into a small QWidget, whichs purpose is only to hold that painted element.

```
void Note::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

    paintExample = new(QWidget);
    paintExample->setGeometry(500,500,500,500);
    paintExample->setStyleSheet("background:yellow");

    QImage *arrowImg = new QImage(100,100,QImage::Format_RGB32);
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(arrowImg); //Error: no matching function for call to 'QHBoxLayout::addWidget(QImage*&)'
    paintExample->setLayout(lay);

    QPainter painter(arrowImg); //Must paint on QImage/QPixmap/QPicture, QWidget not possible?
    if (painter.isActive()){
        painter.begin(arrowImg);
        painter.setPen(Qt::black);
        QRect rect = QRect(50,25,60,40);
        painter.drawRect(rect);
        painter.end();
    }
    paintExample->show();
}
```

In the class header in private area:

```
QWidget * paintExample;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation carefully:

- [QHBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html), and any other layout, could only hold items inheriting from [QLayoutItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html), which are QLayout itself, QSpacerItem and QWidgetItem. Create QWidget and paint on that.
- [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) constructor accepts descendants from [QPaintDevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpaintdevice.html) and QWidget is among those, so it's totally possible.

Now, to other issues:

- You create parentless objects in `paintEvent()` without deleting them. Not only this method could be called quite frequently, this approach to painting is not good at all. As I understand `Note` is a QWidget already, so you're free to paint on it right away, with `QPainter painter(this);`.
- Operations with layout are most definitely not meant to be done in `paintEvent()` either, as well as  showing/hiding widgets. Do this somewhere else, e.g. in your window/dialog constructor.

Comment: I make all this stuff because I want to draw an arrow between the Note-Widget and another widget working as a menu. The arrow should be placed over the note but under the menu, so that it looks like as if the arrow belongs to the window decoration of the menu. So I can't paint to Note...

Comment: And how can I paint to Note, it is no QPicture, nor QImage, nor QPixmap

Comment: You're not listening to what has been said. QPainter constructor **accepts** `QWidget*` as its argument since QWidget inherits QPaintDevice.

Comment: Take a look at other Qt [examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-widgets.html), like [Analog Clock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-analogclock.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I add my widget to the layout?

Because `QImage` is not a `QWidget`. That's why. You should probably wrap the image in a `QLabel`:

```
QLabel arrowLabel;
arrowLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*arrowImg));
```

and pass that to the layout:

```
lay->addWidget(arrowLabel);
```

Comment: `no matching function for call to 'QPixmap::fromImage(QImage*&)'
     arrowLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(arrowImg));
                                                     ^`

Comment: @user2366975, it's `QPixmap::fromImage(*arrowImg)`.